# Best way to index, search and store information in C#

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I'm writing an application which will need to index and store information about files fast. I'm currently using XML to store the information using this code:

```
        XmlTextWriter xtw;
        xtw = new XmlTextWriter(FilePath, Encoding.UTF8);
        xtw.WriteStartDocument();
        xtw.WriteStartElement("ApplicationIndex");
        xtw.WriteEndElement();
        xtw.Close(); 

        XmlDocument xd = new XmlDocument();
        FileStream lfile = new FileStream(FilePath, FileMode.Open);
        xd.Load(lfile);
        XmlElement cl = xd.CreateElement("Application");
        cl.SetAttribute("Name", ApplicationName);
        XmlElement na = xd.CreateElement("Path");
        XmlText natext = xd.CreateTextNode(ApplicationPath);
        na.AppendChild(natext);
        cl.AppendChild(na);
        XmlElement na1 = xd.CreateElement("UseCount");
        XmlText natext1 = xd.CreateTextNode("0");
        na1.AppendChild(natext1);
        cl.AppendChild(na1);
        XmlElement na2 = xd.CreateElement("SearchTerm");
        XmlText natext2 = xd.CreateTextNode(ApplicationName.ToLower());
        na2.AppendChild(natext2);
        cl.AppendChild(na2);
        xd.DocumentElement.AppendChild(cl);
        lfile.Close();
        xd.Save(FilePath);
```

This works fine for creating the file and storing the data, however I'm having trouble searching through the data quickly as there are several hundred nodes in the document. I've tried using Linq to XML to achieve this using this code:

```
        listBox1.Items.Clear();
        var doc = XDocument.Load(filePath);
        foreach (var child in doc.Descendants("SearchTerm"))
        {
            if (child.Value.Contains(textBox1.Text.ToLower()))
            {
                listBox1.Items.Add(child.Value);
            }
        }
```

This is very fast however I can't seem to get any information about the selected node. For example I would like to sort the returned results based upon the UseCount (The higher the count the higher up the list). Is there anyway to do this in XML or any other technique to achieve this?

This is what the XML file looks like:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ApplicationIndex>
  <Application Name="Google Chrome">
    <Path>C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Chrome.exe</Path>
    <UseCount>0</UseCount>
    <SearchTerm>google chrome</SearchTerm>
  </Application>
  <Application Name="Mozilla Firefox">
    <Path>C:\Program Files\Mozilla\Firefox\Firefox.exe</Path>
    <UseCount>0</UseCount>
    <SearchTerm>mozilla firefox</SearchTerm>
  </Application>
</ApplicationIndex>
```

Comment: can you show the xml structure ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can Sort your elements by `UseCount` in *descending* order like this:

```
var doc = XDocument.Load(filePath);
var elements = doc.Descendants("Application")
               .OrderByDescending(x => (int)x.Element("UseCount"));
```

In order to search a record by given `SearchTerm` you can do the following:

```
var element = doc.Descendants("Application")
             .FirstOrDefault(x => (string)x.Element("SearchTerm") == value);

if(element != null)
{
    // record found
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works but the search bit requires me to type in the whole phrase. Is there a way to search if the value contains the search term?

Comment: Got this error: Error 1 'System.Xml.Linq.XElement' does not contain a definition for 'Contains' and the best extension method overload 'System.Linq.ParallelEnumerable.Contains<TSource>(System.Linq.ParallelQuery<TSource>, TSource)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: @KieranCrown you can try:  `((string)x.Element("SearchTerm")).Contains(value)`

Comment: @KieranCrown use `Where` instead of `FirstOrDefault`

Comment: This is the current code I've got: '            listBox1.Items.Clear();
            var doc = XDocument.Load(filePath);
            var element = doc.Descendants("Application")
             .Where(x => ((string)x.Element("SearchTerm")).Contains(textBox1.Text));
            foreach (XElement w in element)
            {
                listBox1.Items.Add(w.Element("Path").Value);
            }' It works but doesn't sort by UseCount?

Comment: if you have another questions, ask another question.I cannot answer all of your questions. I have included the code for `Sorting`, you didn't even write it and still asking me ?